# Thingsboard behind Nginx - Getting mqtt communication

Tags: nginx, networking, mqtt, esp32, thingsboard

I am having some difficulties with getting Thingsboard working behind my reverse proxy. There are actually at least two problems, which i am unfortunately not able to solve by myself.

I have a set up, where i have different vms running on proxmox at my server at home. One is a VM running nginx proxy manager, which is accessable from outside and which i am using as a reverse proxy. This works great for e.g. my nextcloud instance, which is also running in a vm on proxmox.

Now i do have installed a thingsboards instance in a vm and using a esp32 to send some temperature data via mqtt. For that i am using the "Thingsboard arduino sdk", which works great as long as i am staying inside my home network.
In the future a gsm module should be added to the project and should be used for sending the data to the server. For that i am trying to make it run with giving the esp a webadress instead of the ip of the vm.

I looked into the code of the thingsboard arduino sdk. In thingsboard.h the connect function is defined it is written:
`inline const bool connect(const char *host, const char *access_token = PROV_ACCESS_TOKEN, const uint16_t port = 1883, const char *client_id = DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID, const char *password = nullptr)` which tells me that the port 1883 is used as default port for the mqtt communication (also seems plausible because it a typicall mqtt port). Now i added a "Stream" in my nginx proxy manager, giving it the incoming port 1883 and letting him forwarding to the ip of the vm and the port 1883. If i am giving my esp32 now the webadress i am expecting to happens as follows:
mqtt package is send to server behind the domain to port 1883 -> nginx proxy manager |
nginx procy manager sees package on 1883 -> forwarding to vms ip to port 1883.

Should be exactly the same as if i am just giving the esp the ip of my thingsboard vm. Unfortunately thingsboard is not recieving any data and the esp is communicating that it can not connect to thingsboard.

Second problem is probably related: I am using the nginx to forward thingsboard.myserver.com to the thingsboardvm:8080 - which works fine. I am then creating a dashboard and a public link to it. When i am opening the link, the dashboard appears but the charts are staying empty. This does not happens when i am replacing "thingsboard.myserver.com" in the link with the ip from the thingsboard vm. Does anybody know what is happening there? I am doing that for fun and am really interested in learning what is going here....

UPDATE: This Problem could be solved by activating Websocket support in nginx. I found that out by using the tip of Yarin_007 below: Use `f12` in browser to observe what is wrong, here: requests starting with wss:// did not get any answer and were throwing errors.

The ESP Code:

```
#include "DHT.h"
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ThingsBoard.h>

#define WIFI_AP "--WIFI--"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "--PASSWORD--"

#define TOKEN "--TEST_TOKEN--"

// DHT
#define DHTPIN 14
#define DHTTYPE DHT11

char thingsboardServer[] = "--THINGSBOARD SERVER IP--";

WiFiClient wifiClient;

// Initialize DHT sensor.
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

ThingsBoard tb(wifiClient);

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
unsigned long lastSend;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  dht.begin();
  delay(10);
  InitWiFi();
  lastSend = 0;
}

void loop()
{
  if ( !tb.connected() ) {
    reconnect();
  }

  if ( millis() - lastSend > 1000 ) { // Update and send only after 1 seconds
    getAndSendTemperatureAndHumidityData();
    lastSend = millis();
  }

  tb.loop();
}

void getAndSendTemperatureAndHumidityData()
{
  Serial.println("Collecting temperature data.");

  // Reading temperature or humidity takes about 250 milliseconds!
  float humidity = dht.readHumidity();
  // Read temperature as Celsius (the default)
  float temperature = dht.readTemperature();

  // Check if any reads failed and exit early (to try again).
  if (isnan(temperature)) {
    Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT sensor!");
    return;
  }
  if (isnan(humidity)) {
    Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT sensor! - humidity is nan");
    return;
  }

  Serial.println("Sending data to ThingsBoard:");
  Serial.print("Humidity: ");
  Serial.print(humidity);
  Serial.print(" %\t");
  Serial.print("Temperature: ");
  Serial.print(temperature);
  Serial.println(" *C ");

  tb.sendTelemetryFloat("temperature", temperature);
  tb.sendTelemetryFloat("humidity", humidity);
}

void InitWiFi()
{
  Serial.println("Connecting to AP ...");
  // attempt to connect to WiFi network

  WiFi.begin(WIFI_AP, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to AP");
}


void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!tb.connected()) {
    status = WiFi.status();
    if ( status != WL_CONNECTED) {
      WiFi.begin(WIFI_AP, WIFI_PASSWORD);
      while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
      }
      Serial.println("Connected to AP");
    }
    Serial.print("Connecting to ThingsBoard node ...");
    if ( tb.connect(thingsboardServer, TOKEN) ) {
      Serial.println( "[DONE]" );
    } else {
      Serial.print( "[FAILED]" );
      Serial.println( " : retrying in 5 seconds]" );
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay( 5000 );
    }
  }
}
```

The nginx proxy manager divides its config files as far as i can see. I think the relevant config is found in data/nginx/stream/1.conf and looks as follows:

```
server {
  listen 1883;
listen [::]:1883;

  proxy pass --THINGSBOARD SERVER IP:1883;
  # Custom
  include /data/nginx/custom/server stream[.]conf;
  include /data/nginx/custom/server stream tcp[.].conf;
}
```

I appreciate any help! Thank you very much!

// Stack Overflow gave me two boxes to describe my problem, so here is the "What i already tried" part in a bit shorter and compact: //
Tried to forwards mqtt packages to a thingsboard server with nginx. Expected it to work the same way as if i am using the ip of the server instead.

I already tried:

- Configuring a stream in nginx proxy manager for forwarding anything which is coming in on port 1883
- Configuring proxy host via http to forward to thingsboard log-in page/ dashboard. -> log-in no problems, dashboard some problem with getting the data to display
- Forwarding also port 8883 (also mqtt)
- using the nginx local ip inside my network - not sure but i somehow expected nginx also to forward that, if i adress port 1883? -> it does not??
- Trying to specify another port in the esp32 code and on the thingsboard server. No differences.
- different ways to write the adress: "mqqt://myserver.de" , "mqtt://www.myserver.de", ...
- screaming and crying

Comment: those `includes` feel a bit off. are those the actual file names? (well nginx wouldn't have started otherwise, but still.) do you restart nginx between changes? what happens when you run `nginx -t`? As for your 2nd problem - go to `thingsboard.myserver.com`, open the `devtools` with `f12`. make sure the "disable cache" checkbox is checked. Go to the network tab and refresh the page. What do you see? now try again when you instead browse to the IP address.

Comment: In addition to the above `proxy pass` should be [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.html) (note the underscore). Can you please also clarify your setup; port 8080 is generally HTTP whereas 1883 is MQTT (and your config file does not match the question text). You are trying to start with quite a complicated setup; can you start with the basics (e.g. connect directly to Thingsboard from your ESP) and then add the proxy in when the basic setup is working?

Comment: I havent rebooted nginx in between. With proxy hosts it works directly after making the changes. I think that the proxy manager is doing the work for me and restart the necessary services, but i will try!
Thank you for the tip with the disable cache! I will also try that out. 
Clarification: On 8080 the Thingsboard"Website" is displayed and i am using nginx to make it reachable, which works more or less (see dashboard). On 1883 the server is recieving the mqtt data, which is not working. It works by directly connecting the esp without nginx by using the ip in my homenetwork.

Comment: @Yarin_007 The second problem is solved! Thank you very much. I used the devtools and observed that ```wss://``` request were throwing a error. This was because websocket was deactivatet in nginx. I activatet it and now the dashboard can also be accessed from outside! Great! Unfortunately the first error still persist :/ anybody any ideas? I also appreciate ideas what the next step for investigating the error could be!
Also yes, these are the true filenames. Nginx Proxy Manager creates a own config for each proxy and is just giving it ids, starting with one ..

Comment: I also run the ```nginx -t``` command. It says: "the configuration file ----/nginx.conf syntax is ok" and "configuration file ----/nginx.conf test is successful". So that does not seem to be the problem ...

Comment: Please update your question to reflect the fixes made so it's clear what your current issues are (ideally you should be asking [one question at a time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735) even if that means raising two questions).

Comment: Not sure what exactly you try to accomplish, there is no such thing as MQTT server, there is only MQTT broker, if you have some sensor nodes out in the field that publish the MQTT message to a broker, you need to have a MQTT client that "subscribe" to the same broker to "listen" to the topic published by all the sensors, and parse the data, and write it into database or do something with it. If you want to host your own MQTT broker within your network instead of using a public MQTT broker, all need is to port forward the MQTT ports on your router, there is nothing need to involve nginx.

Comment: You are right. The right wording is broker! As far as i understand thingsboard is already providing a mqtt broker at port 1883. The general set up with mqtt seems to work, as it works if i let my esp32 work inside my local network by using the ip of the vm which is running thingsboard. I now want to send the data from the esp32 from *outside* of my local network and want to use my domain for it. I do have a nginx proxy manager for handling all the traffic and distribute it to different vms. For mqtt it should work with a tcp stream - Everythings on domain:1883 -> thingsboard vm ip. It does not

Comment: "from outside of my local network" so is port 1883 getting to nginx? (you don't say whether your nginx server has an internet attached NIC or if there is a firewall/router in between). Add `access_log` to your config to confirm this (alternatively try connecting your ESP to `nginx.local.IP:1883`). Please post updated config taking feedback received so far into account.

Comment: Yes. The general setup is as follows: I do have a server running here. On that proxmox is running and in proxmox different vms. One of that is nginx. In my router i opened the nginx vm ports 80, 443 and 1883. Nginx is in use as a proxy to make different vms available via there thirdlevel domain part. It works great for my thingsboard dashboard, nextcloud etc.. Now i setted up a tcp stream, which i am expecting to redirect everything on port 1883 on nginx through the router to the thingsboard vm. I give the esp my domain for mqqt. That does not work. If i give it the the ip of the vm it works.

Comment: I have not changed any configs for the stream set up. I just changed the config for the proxy https redirect for the thingsboard dashboard. In nginx proxy manager webui it is just a switch, but i will look for the config! I am sorry that i asked to questions. I thought that they would be related, but it seems just to make everything more confusing ..

Answer (score 0):

I solved it/ found a work arround. Thank you all for your input, it helped me a lot and i also learned a lot! Also sorry for asking two questions, that will not happen again!!

***The solutions are:***

*1. Not getting mqtt data to the thingsboard vm:*
I just skipped nginx and opened the port 1883 of the vm directly in my router. This seems to be the obvious approach and i dont know why i didnt try that earlier. Anyways, it works!

*2. Getting the dashboard available from outside:*
To clearify the problem again: The dashboard was shown, but no data was displayed. This is because the data for the dashboard is send via websocket, which was deactivated in nginx. So make sure to activate it!

Thank you very much for your help! Looks like i did some really basic errors.